# new List <T> in generic class implementation

Tags: c#, generics

Trying to create a generic implementation of a list. my class will be:

```
public class SpecialList <T>
{ 
    private List <T> mylist;

    public void SpecialList <T>() 
    { 
        mylist = new List <T>()
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile b/c "cannot implicitly convert type ....List  to ... List ... " what am I missing ?

Comment: Thanks @Phil, sgs2 firefox is not friendly to SO editor...

Comment: System.Collections.Generics.List

Comment: You have two choices: Inherit from List<T> or have a class to contain a List<T>. In your example you chose the latter. IS that what you want?

Comment: *Trying to create a generic implementation of a list* [Microsoft beat you to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: :-) I am extending ms List....

Comment: @Dani: No, you're *not* extending list in the normal OO sense - your composing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems with this line:

```
public void SpecialList <T>()
```

Firstly, you're declaring a *method* with a `void` return type, when I suspect you want it to be a constructor.

Secondly, it's a *generic* method - which introduces a new type parameter `T` which is unrelated to the existing type parameter. That's why the conversion doesn't work. Imagine it was written as:

```
public void MyGenericMethod<TOther>()
{
    List<T> x = new List<TOther>();
}
```

... then it would be obviously wrong, yes?

You just want a constructor like this:

```
public SpecialList()
{
    ...
}
```

(As a side-note, usually the type parameter isn't separated from the declaration by a space, as you've done. It's normally `List<T>` rather than `List <T>` for example. It may be worth changing your habits to match the conventions most other people use.)

Comment: Thanks, I was typing the code into my mobile, the space is not in the source code. I'm not even sure it compile with a space. Anyways, you were right about it. my original idea was to create a special version of List<T> which is thread safe to my purposes. currnetly I went for a non generic implementation as I've needed to do some manipulation on T itself....

Answer (score 4):

Your class should be

```
public class SpecialList <T>
{ 
    private List <T> mylist;

    public SpecialList() 
    { 
        mylist = new List <T>();
    }
}
```

and of course if your class is to look like a collection, you may want to implement one or more collection interfaces, e.g.

```
public class SpecialList <T> : ICollection<T>
{ 
    private List <T> mylist;

    public SpecialList() 
    { 
        mylist = new List <T>();
    }

    // ICollection<T>.Add
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // delegate to myList
        myList.Add(item);
    }

    ... /Clear/Contains/CopyTo/ etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the construct which can't be *defined* as `void SpecialList<T>()`:

```
public class SpecialList<T> {
    private List<T> mylist;

    public SpecialList( ) {
        mylist = new List<T>( );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can not define a constructor with any Generic Parameters.
what you could do is simply remove generic specific code.

```
public class SpecialList <T>
{ 
    private List <T> mylist;

    public SpecialList() 
    { 
        mylist = new List <T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that *T* in the constructor.

It makes the compiler think it is a type other than the *T* used on class.

That is why it says cannot convert it from *List* (where *T* is from class) to *List* (where *T* is from constructor).